# How to add some additional columns to the log listener?

Tags: testing, logging, jmeter

I need to add more columns to the log listener, such as the name of the sampler, number of iterations, number of server. How can I do it?
I must add these columns to the existing file logs.

Comment: `I must add these columns to the existing file logs.` Spells T-R-O-U-B-L-E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners can be configured to save different items to the result log files (JTL) by using the Config popup as shown below:

[image: Sample Result Save Configuration popup]

Follow these steps to reach it:

1. Add a Listener, View Results in Table, for example.
2. Set the "Filename" field with desired log file name.
3. Click "Configure" button to choose more data to save.

The defaults are defined in the [Listener Default Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) section of the user guide.
Get more information at [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) user manual.

See also [CSV log format](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#csvlogformat)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which information to store in .jtl results file by applying [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) in *user.properties* file.

If there is appropriate JMeter Property which holds the value you would like to have in the log - there is a possibility to store an arbitrary [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value via [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property

Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article to learn more about JMeter configuration via properties and ways of setting and overriding them.